# running multiple commands in cmd with Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am trying to use `cmd` from Delphi to apply some commands. I use following code

```
ShellExecute(Application.handle, 'runas', 'cmd.exe',
  PChar('/c command to do '), nil, SW_show);
```

I want to run more than one command in the same execution, for example

```
/c command1 command2 command3
```

I already made a bat file to run some commands. But I don't like the idea of storing a bat to my project. Can I apply more than one command in one execution? Can this be done?

Comment: Do you need to use a command interpreter. Can't you use API functions instead.

Comment: i dont know if there is api to do commands instead of using cmd it self in delphi i will search about that

Comment: How do you think cmd does it. It isn't turtles all the way down.

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin IOW, what specific commands are you wanting to run? There is most likely API functions to accomplish the same actions more directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i will run some netsh commands , the answer helps to do all of them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try separating commands with &&, here is working example

```
  ShellExecute(Application.handle, 'open', 'cmd.exe',
    PChar('/c "copy /Y file1.txt file2.txt&&copy /Y file2.txt file3.txt"'), nil, SW_show);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! As a side note, one must declare the `ShellAPI` in the `Uses` first